# Why is this equation true?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How is $e^{2x}$ equal to  $e^x+e^{-x}$ ?
I'm totally mad that I don't get it. Thanks.

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Comment: Check value at zero ....these are not equal

Comment: Is it possible that you were being asked to *solve* $e^{2x} = e^x + e^{-x}$?

Answer (score 2):

that's not correct 
$$e^{2x}=e^xe^x=(e^x)^2$$
$$e^x+e^x=2e^x$$
$e^x+e^{-x}$ can't be simplified

$e^x+e^{-x}=e^{2x}$ can be true for a certain value of x but not $\forall \, x$

Answer (score 1):

They are not equal.

$$e^{2\cdot 0}= 1\neq 2= e^0 + e^{-0}$$

We do have

$$e^{2x} = e^x \div e^{-x}$$

and I do have experience of mistook $\div$ as $+$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$e^{2x} = e^x+e^{-x}$,
let
$y = e^x$.
Then
$e^{2x} = y^2$
and
$e^{-x} = 1/y$.

The equation becomes
$y^2 = y+1/y$.
Multiplying by $y$,
this becomes
$y^3 = y^2+1$.

This
(according to Wolfy)
 has one real root
(about $1.4656$)
and two conjugate complex roots
(about $-0.23279 \pm 0.79255 i$).
The algebraic expressions
are the usual cubic mess
and do not seem interesting.

The $x$ corresponding
to the real root
is about $0.382245$.